# How to show a splash screen onLoadStart?

Tags: flutter, webview

I am making my first Flutter app and I have a question. I am using the plugin flutter_inappwebview and I want to show a full screen splash/load screen. Preferably with a Lottie animation. The code I have so far:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
   return Scaffold(
       body: Container(
           child: Column(children: <Widget>[
             Expanded(
               child: Stack(
                 children: [
                   InAppWebView(
                     key: webViewKey,
                     initialUrlRequest:
                     URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")),
                     initialUserScripts: UnmodifiableListView<UserScript>([]),
                     initialOptions: options,
                     pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                     onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                       webViewController = controller;
                     },
                     onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
                       setState(() {
                         this.url = url.toString();
                         urlController.text = this.url;
                       });
                     },
                     androidOnPermissionRequest:
                         (controller, origin, resources) async {
                       return PermissionRequestResponse(
                           resources: resources,
                           action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                     },
                     shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                         (controller, navigationAction) async {
                       var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                       if (![
                         "http",
                         "https",
                         "file",
                         "chrome",
                         "data",
                         "javascript",
                         "about"
                       ].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                         if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                           // Launch the App
                           await launch(
                             url,
                           );
                           // and cancel the request
                           return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                         }
                       }

                       return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                     },
                     onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                     
                     },

                     onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                       pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                     },
                     onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                       if (progress == 100) {
                         pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                       }
                       setState(() {
                         this.progress = progress / 100;
                         urlController.text = this.url;
                       });
                     },
                     onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                       setState(() {
                         this.url = url.toString();
                         urlController.text = this.url;
                       });
                     },
                     onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                       print(consoleMessage);
                     },
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             ),

           ])));
 }
}
```

I am a beginner in Flutter so if you have a solution, please make it simple. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onLoadStart` parameter let's you know when the loading start, so you'll never be able to put a splash screen there, your second option would be to use the `isLoading` method that comes from the `webviewController`, it returns `true or false` for when the page is completely loaded and when it is loading.

So you can use that and setup a splashScreen and then show the splash screen when it is `true` and the take it out when it is `false`.

```
   bool _isLoading = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:
            Container(
                child: _isLoading
                    ? Center(
                        child: SpinKitChasingDots(
                        size: 50,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ))
                    : Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              InAppWebView(
                                 key: webViewKey,
                                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                                    url: Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")),
                                initialUserScripts:
                                    UnmodifiableListView<UserScript>([]),
                                 initialOptions: options,
                                pullToRefreshController:
                                    pullToRefreshController,
                                onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                                
                                  webViewController = controller;
                                 
                                },
                                onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isLoading = true;
                                  });
                                },
                                androidOnPermissionRequest:
                                    (controller, origin, resources) async {
                                  return PermissionRequestResponse(
                                      resources: resources,
                                      action: PermissionRequestResponseAction
                                          .GRANT);
                                },
                                shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                                    (controller, navigationAction) async {
                                  var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                                  if (![
                                    "http",
                                    "https",
                                    "file",
                                    "chrome",
                                    "data",
                                    "javascript",
                                    "about"
                                  ].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                                    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                                      // Launch the App
                                      await launch(
                                        url,
                                      );
                                      // and cancel the request
                                      return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                                    }
                                  }

                                  return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                                },
                                onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                                  print("We are no longer loading");
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isLoading = false;
                                  });
                                },

                                onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                                   pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                                },
                                onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) async{
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isLoading = false;
                                  });
                                  SpinKitChasingDots();
                                   if (progress == 100) {
                                     pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                                   }
                                   setState(() {
                                     this.progress = progress / 100;
                                     urlController.text = this.url;
                                   });
                                },
                                onUpdateVisitedHistory:
                                    (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    this.url = url.toString();
                                    //  urlController.text = this.url;
                                  });
                                },
                                onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                                  print(consoleMessage);
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ])));
  }
```

In this example I'm manually setting `_isLoading` to `true` and `false`.

This is because I realized there's not much you can do with the controller if the controller is not built, here's an example if you run it you'll notice you stay stuck in the splashscreen.

```
bool _isLoading = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    body:
        Container(
            child: _isLoading
                ? Center(
                    child: SpinKitChasingDots(
                    size: 50,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ))
                : Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          InAppWebView(
                            //  key: webViewKey,
                            initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                                url: Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")),
                            initialUserScripts:
                                UnmodifiableListView<UserScript>([]),
                            //  initialOptions: options,
                            pullToRefreshController:
                                pullToRefreshController,
                            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                              webViewController = controller;
                            },

                            onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
                              setState(() {
                                _isLoading = true;
                              });

                              //  setState(() {
                              //    this.url = url.toString();
                              //    urlController.text = this.url;
                              //  });
                            },
                            androidOnPermissionRequest:
                                (controller, origin, resources) async {
                              return PermissionRequestResponse(
                                  resources: resources,
                                  action: PermissionRequestResponseAction
                                      .GRANT);
                            },
                            shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                                (controller, navigationAction) async {
                              var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                              if (![
                                "http",
                                "https",
                                "file",
                                "chrome",
                                "data",
                                "javascript",
                                "about"
                              ].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                                if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                                  // Launch the App
                                  await launch(
                                    url,
                                  );
                                  // and cancel the request
                                  return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                                }
                              }

                              return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                            },
                            onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                              

                              _isLoading = await controller.isLoading();
                              
                             
                            },

                            onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                              //  pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                            },
                            onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) async{
                              print("Gozimasu");
                              // bool loading = await controller.isLoading();
                              // setState(() {
                                _isLoading = await controller.isLoading();
                              // });
                              // SpinKitChasingDots();
                              //  if (progress == 100) {
                              //    pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                              //  }
                              //  setState(() {
                              //    this.progress = progress / 100;
                              //    urlController.text = this.url;
                              //  });
                            },
                            onUpdateVisitedHistory:
                                (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                              setState(() {
                                this.url = url.toString();
                                //  urlController.text = this.url;
                              });
                            },
                            onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                              print(consoleMessage);
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ])));
```

}

Comment: Hello! Thanks for you answer. It worked for me! Thank you for helping me. Is it possible to do a fade out of the loading animation?

Comment: You can do that too, you just have to build the widget first